# nx build app watch mode doesn't work when using incremental

Tags: nrwl-nx, incremental-build

Title says pretty much it.

I followed steps from this official nx [Incremental Build Angular](https://nx.dev/recipes/other/setup-incremental-builds-angular) guide on how to use the buildLibsFromSource flag, but it only refers to the "nx serve" command.
I have to use "nx build" instead and was able to run it but when I change something in one of my libraries, build is not triggered. Other [official resource](https://nx.dev/more-concepts/incremental-builds) does not really help on this neither.

Anyone has insights on this ?